# then what is $f(-5)=?$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Let $f(x)=\arcsin(\dfrac{2x}{x^2+1})+2\arctan x  \ : \ |x| \geq 1$ then what is $f(-5)=?$

Let $-5=x=\tan \alpha$ now $$f(\tan \alpha)=\arcsin(\sin 2\alpha)+2\arctan (\tan \alpha)$$
now what do i do ?

Comment: Why exactly are you introducing $\tan\alpha$ into the computation?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri since $\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ Similar $\frac{2\tan \alpha}{\tan^2\alpha+1}$

Comment: Well, then you've got the question practically nailed down. What are the possible values of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
f'(x) &=&{1\over \sqrt{1-{4x^2\over (x^2+1)^2}}}\cdot {-2x^2+2\over (x^2+1)^2}-{2\over 1+x^2}\\
&=&{x^2+1\over \sqrt{(x^2-1)^2}}\cdot {-2(x^2-1)\over (x^2+1)^2}-{2\over 1+x^2}\\
&=&{1\over |x^2-1|}\cdot {-2(x^2-1)\over x^2+1}-{2\over 1+x^2}\\
&=&0
\end{eqnarray}

So $f$ is constant function on $(-\infty, -1)$ and on $(1,\infty)$ and thus $$f(-5)= f(-\sqrt{3})=\arcsin {-\sqrt{3}\over 2}+2\arctan (-\sqrt{3}) = -\pi$$

Comment: but $f(-5)\neq f(1)$

Comment: That calculation doesn't work for $x=\pm 1$, and once you exclude those two points, the domain is not connected anymore, so you can only claim it is constant on subintervals.

Comment: Ok, that is easly reperable. $f(-5) = f(-\sqrt{3})=...-\pi$

Answer (score 1):

There is some $\alpha\in (-\pi/2,0)$ with $\tan \alpha = -5$.
In this case:

$$f(-5)=\arcsin\left(\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+(\tan\alpha)^2}\right)+2\arctan(\tan\alpha)$$

Like you observed, $\sin(2\alpha)=\frac{2\tan\alpha}{1+(\tan\alpha)^2}$, and hence

$$f(-5)=\arcsin(\sin(2\alpha))+2\arctan(\tan\alpha)$$

Now, $\arctan(\tan x)=x$ whenever $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, so one of the terms is pretty simple.
Similarly, $\arcsin(\sin x)=x$ whenever $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.
We hence need to verify whether or not $\alpha \in (-\pi/4,\pi/4)$.

This is not the case: $\tan(-\pi/4)=-1$, and hence $\alpha$ lies below $-\pi/4$, that is $\alpha \in (-\pi/2,-\pi/4)$.
It follows that $2\alpha\in(-\pi,-\pi/2)$.
In this case, we can observe that

$$\sin(2\alpha)=\sin(\pi-2\alpha)=\sin(-\pi-2\alpha),$$

where first we used the reflection identity $\sin(\theta)=\sin(\pi-\theta)$, and then used the $2\pi$-periodicty of the sine.
Notice that $-\pi-2\alpha \in (-\pi/2,0)$, and thus:

$$f(-5)=\arcsin(\sin(-\pi-2\alpha))+2\arctan(\tan\alpha)=-\pi-2\alpha+2\alpha=-\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arctan x=y,-\dfrac\pi2<y<\dfrac\pi2, x=\tan y$

$\arcsin\dfrac{2x}{x^2+1}=\arcsin(\sin2y)=\begin{cases}2y&\mbox{if }-\dfrac\pi2\le2y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-1\le\tan y\le1 \\ 
\pi-2y & \mbox{if }-\dfrac\pi2\le\pi-2y\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\dfrac\pi4\le y\le\dfrac{3\pi}4\iff x=\tan y\ge1\\-\pi-2y& \mbox{if }-\dfrac{3\pi}4\le y\le-\dfrac{\pi}4\iff x\le-1\end{cases} $

Answer (score 1):

Let's continue where you stopped, with also restricting ourselves to $|\alpha|\lt\frac {\pi}{2}$ giving us $\arctan x=\arctan(\tan\alpha)=\alpha $. It is *tempting* to do the same with $\arcsin $ and claim that $\arcsin (\sin 2\alpha)=2\alpha $; however, this is *not* correct, and actually we need to distinguish the following cases:

- For $x\le -1$, i.e. $-\frac {\pi}{2}\lt\alpha\le-\frac {\pi}{4} $, we have $-{\pi}\lt2\alpha\le\frac {\pi}{2} $, so $\arcsin(\sin 2\alpha)=-\pi-2\alpha $ and $f (x)=-\pi-2\alpha+2\alpha=-\pi $.
- For $-1\le x\le 1$, we have $-\frac {\pi}{4}\le\alpha\le\frac {\pi}{4} $, i.e. $-\frac {\pi}{2}\le2\alpha\le\frac {\pi}{2} $, so $\arcsin(\sin 2\alpha)=2\alpha $ and $f (x)=4\alpha=4\arctan x $.
- Finally, for $x\ge 1$, i.e. $\frac {\pi}{4}\le\alpha\lt\frac {\pi}{2} $, we have $\frac{\pi}{2}\le 2\alpha\lt\pi$, so $\arcsin(\sin 2\alpha)=\pi-2\alpha $ and $f (x)=\pi-2\alpha+2\alpha=\pi $.

Thus, it seems that:

$$f (x)=\begin {cases}-\pi & x\le -1 \\ 4\arctan x & -1\le x\le 1 \\ \pi & x\ge 1 \end {cases} $$

Finally, $f (-5)=-\pi $.